# Is possible to duplicate 2 o more layers at a time in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, layers

I made a design with 7 layers, and now I have to do another one very similar but with different attributes (text, color, size,etc).

I know I can duplicate each layer, but **can I duplicate 2 or more of them at a time?**

**Additionally** if it's possible, **can I move them as if they were an unique object?** (without merging/losing the each particular layer characteristics )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a layer group and move both layers there, then you can duplicate that layer group.

Depending on your workflow, layer groups might be a major improvement for other tasks as well, because you can e.g. switch their visibility more easily than that of all the layers they contain.

You can't move layer groups and their layers yet, unfortunately - but you can link all the layers you want to move in the layers dialog, and then move them all together.

[image: GIMP layers dialog with layer groups and linked layers]

Comment: Great this is what I needed. BTW it seems that I'm able to move the whole group together in the workspace.

Comment: In Gimp 2.10, groups have improved somewhat, you can have a layer mask on the group and apply geometric transforms to the group as a whole, so groups are closer to behaving exactly like layers.